# Should the merging of 2 stored procedure result sets be done on the database side or on the API side?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Below is the API and I need to make a new Stored Procedure to return this. The upper part before the "MemberCard" has a Stored Procedure that can output it, and the sub-details of the "MemberCard" has its own stored procedure also. How do I combine the result sets of the 2 stored procedures in the same format below? or should the Java API be the one to merge the result sets of the 2 sp's?

Sample Response:

```
{  
   "Action":"MemberLogin3",
   "CardNumber":"00000376",
   "MemberMobilePhone":"94600240",
   "SMSValidation":1,
   "MemberToken":"",
   "PWDFailRetryCount":10,
   "CheckResult":"0",
   "EmailValidation":1,
   "ResponseCode":0,
   "Type":"Manual",
   "MemberCreatedOn":"2014-12-16 09:33:04",
   "MemberID":49,
   "MemberDefLanguage":"us",
   "CountryCode":"00852",
   "ReadReguFlag":0,
   "MemberCard":[  
      {  
         "OctopusID":"12455678|0",
         "BrandPicGFile":"",
         "CardTypeName":"",
         "CardExpiryDate":"2075-04-01",
         "CardGradePicFile":"/tap/FileManagement/26/20120702_629Tvi.png",
         "MinPointPreAdd":"",
         "MinPointPreTransfer":"",
         "TotalPoints":"1000",
         "CardGrade":"1",
         "BrandID":"1",
         "MaxPointPreTransfer":"0",
         "MemberSex":"2",
         "HomeTelNum":"29504288",
         "BrandPicSFile":"",
         "MemberEngGivenName":"",
         "CountryCode":"852",
         "MaxAmountPreTransfer":"",
         "LaserID":"",
         "MaxAmountPreAdd":"1000.0000",
         "CardNumber":"000100086",
         "CardPointToAmountRate":"100.000000",
         "GracePeriodValue":"",
         "BrandPicMFile":"",
         "MaxPointPreAdd":"",
         "MinAmountPreAdd":"100.0000",
         "MemberRegisterMobile":"85294906037",
         "CardGradeNotes":"",
         "MemberYearofBirth":"1985",
         "GracePeriodUnit":"",
         "MemberIdentityRef":"",
         "MemberEngFamilyName":"",
         "MemberIdentityType":"",
         "MemberMonthofBirth":"6",
         "CardGradeMaxPoint":"",
         "CardTypeID":"",
         "MemberDayofBirth":"1985-06-04",
         "MemberChiFamilyName":"",
         "MemberChiGivenName":"",
         "MinAmountPreTransfer":"",
         "CardStatus":"2",
         "TotalAmount":"1000.00",
         "CardAmountToPointRate":"1.000000",
         "MemberMobilePhone":"94906037",
         "CardAmountExpiryDate":"2013-10-17",
         "CardPointExpiryDate":"2013-10-17",
         "UpdatedOn":"2014-04-17 14:50:10",
         "MemberQRCode":"Q7FM1110339d9b35928d4b8f09235b87a4cd1dd23cf404b"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what you can do to combine resultset into single SP

1. Assuming your table names are Member (master table) and MemberCard (child table) and has one to many relationship from Member to MemberCard.
2. Left Join the master (Member) and child (Membercard) table which would produce single result set. This would produce one row per membercard that means you will get duplicate member details if a member has multiple MemberCards and null values for MemberCard if Member does not have MemberCard.
3. In your JAVA api you can perform in memory grouping on member and produce desired object structure you mentioned.

Example query for stored procedure,

```
SELECT 
 M.Action,
 M.CardNumber,
 M.MemberMobilePhone,
 M.SMSValidation,
 M.MemberToken
 --Other fields from Member table
 MC.OctopusID,
 MC.BrandPicGFile,
 MC.CardTypeName,
 MC.CardExpiryDate
 -- Other fields from MemberCard table

FROM Member M
LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberCard MC ON MC.MemberId = M.MemberId
--Your filter conditions etc
```

You have not mentioned purpose of combining into single SP but if you are looking to reduce database calls then you can consider above approach. Also, if you have large resultset apply paging in your SQL Query.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is sufficient.